# Make ContentDocument private in bulk?

Tags: trigger, sharing, contentversion, contentdocument, admin

Is there a way to change the sharing setting for contentdocuments that has been shared to "Any user in your company" as viewer to be private to only be accessed by the owner via script/programmatically?
[image]

Comment: This is controlled by the ContentDocumentLink object.  This can be done with Apex, not sure if Flow can access this object.

Comment: Thanks, @DavidCheng